# Python-3 Trying to iterate through a csv and get http response codes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to read a csv file that contains a long list of urls. I need to iterate through the list and get the urls that throw a 301, 302, or 404 response. In trying to test the script I am getting an exited with code 0 so I know it is error free but it is not doing what I need it to. I am new to python and working with files, my experience has been ui automation primarily. Any suggestions would be gladly appreciated. Below is the code.

```
import csv
import requests
import responses
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open('redirect.csv', 'r')
contents = []
with open('redirect.csv', 'r') as csvf:  # Open file in read mode
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)
    for url in urls:
        contents.append(url)  # Add each url to list contents
    


def run():
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    print(self.url, resp.getcode())
    run()


print(run)
```

Comment: can you add the csv header and 1 or 2 rows?

Answer (score 1):

Given you have a CSV similar to the following (the heading is URL)

```
URL
https://duckduckgo.com
https://bing.com
```

You can do something like this using the [requests library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

```py
import csv
import requests

with open('urls.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    errors = []
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    # Iterate through each line of the csv file
    for row in reader:
        try:
            r = requests.get(row['URL'])
            if r.status_code in [301, 302, 404]:
                # print(f"{r.status_code}: {row['url']}")
                errors.append([row['url'], r.status_code])
        except:
            pass
```

Uncomment the print statement if you want to see the results in the terminal. The code at the moment appends a list of URL and status code to an `errors` list. You can print or continue processing this if you prefer.

Comment: Brilliant! This worked like a charm. Thank you Stu!

Comment: Glad it worked for you! If it solved your problem you should mark the answer as the solution so Stu can score some points.